# How do I use bind_rows in a list of table?

Tags: r

Suppose I have three tables as below:

```
table1 <- structure(list(Pos = 1:6, A = c(16.8508287292818, 0, 0.552486187845304, 
0, 1.10497237569061, 1.38121546961326), C = c(1.93370165745856, 
0.276243093922652, 0.828729281767956, 0.276243093922652, 0, 0.552486187845304
), G = c(1.10497237569061, 2.48618784530387, 0.276243093922652, 
0.828729281767956, 0.276243093922652, 0), T = c(0.828729281767956, 
0, 0.828729281767956, 1.10497237569061, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Pos", 
"A", "C", "G", "T"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

table2<- structure(list(Pos = 1:6, A = c(4.15584415584416, 1.03896103896104, 
0.779220779220779, 0.692640692640693, 2.25108225108225, 2.94372294372294
), C = c(1.12554112554113, 0.173160173160173, 0.173160173160173, 
0.519480519480519, 0.173160173160173, 0.173160173160173), G = c(1.03896103896104, 
0.346320346320346, 0.0865800865800866, 0.432900432900433, 0.519480519480519, 
0.0865800865800866), T = c(2.77056277056277, 0.606060606060606, 
0.25974025974026, 0.692640692640693, 0.346320346320346, 0.25974025974026
)), .Names = c("Pos", "A", "C", "G", "T"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
table3 <- structure(list(Pos = 1:6, A = c(10.3492063492063, 0.317460317460317, 
0.349206349206349, 0.920634920634921, 1.96825396825397, 1.23809523809524
), C = c(0.825396825396825, 0.126984126984127, 0.349206349206349, 
0.317460317460317, 0.19047619047619, 0.253968253968254), G = c(0.761904761904762, 
0.952380952380952, 0.285714285714286, 0.412698412698413, 0.126984126984127, 
0.19047619047619), T = c(1.07936507936508, 0.412698412698413, 
0.476190476190476, 0.253968253968254, 0.19047619047619, 0.253968253968254
)), .Names = c("Pos", "A", "C", "G", "T"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have now saved the table names as `files.table`:

```
files.table <- paste0("table", seq(1:3))
```

My problem is that I could not run this `bind_rows` function to bind table1, table2 and table3 using `files.table` instead of listing all three tables. This is the error I get: `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names`

This is the code I tried:

```
bind.table <- bind_rows(files.table, .id = "table") %>%
      gather(Base, Percent, -Pos, -table)
```

Comment: Try `files.table <- mget(x = paste0("table", seq(1:3)))` instead. `bind_rows()` won't work on just the object names as characters.

Comment: I'm glad it works, but it's not ideal. The best solution is what I referenced in my other comment below the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.id` argument for `bind_rows` sets the name of the variable containing the name of the list item each row came from, not these names themselves. You set the table names by naming the items in the list. Then, `bind_rows` will get those names and put them into a column with a name you specify:

```
table_list <- list(table1, table2, table3)
names(table_list) <- paste0("table", seq(1:3))
bind.table <- bind_rows(table_list, .id = 'id')
```

From `?bind_rows`:

> Each argument can either be a data frame, a list that could be a data
>   frame, or a list of data frames

The easiest way to get the data frames into `bind_rows` is to assemble them into a list and then just pass the list of data frames in. As @joran suggests, the easiest way to do this is to load or generate them in a `lapply` function which will automatically output a list that can go into `bind_rows`.

Comment: I don't want to type `list(table1, table2, table3)` as I have lots of tables that I am reading from the directory.

Comment: Just get them into a list. It doesn't matter how

Comment: @MAPK If you are reading them from files, then the real solution is to wrap the file reading code in an `lapply` call, so that all the tables are in a list right from the start.

Comment: Exactly! great suggestion @joran